# VBA find function getting error 424 object required

Tags: excel, vba

I have code getting error 424 object required

```
lr = Range("O:O").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For y = 0 To UBound(myVariable)
    a = myVariable(y)
    Range("O:O").Select
    Set objXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set z = Cells.Find(What:=a, After:=Range("O2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If z = "True" Then
        ActiveCell.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
    MsgBox z.Value
Next
```

Comment: A good read http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1):

Find retrieves an range **Object**. So you either:

a) Activate the found range

```
Cells.Find(What:=a, After:=Range("O2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

**OR**

b) Assign the found range to a variable

```
Set z = Cells.Find(What:=a, After:=Range("O2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)      'No .Activate in here '
```

Using both at the same time will produce an error.

**NOTE:**

Be carefull.  If `.Find` does NOT find a match, it will retrieve `Nothing`.  In such a case the `.Activate` will pop an error msg.  So use some error handling in here.